# How i can pass a list<String> to the server with url

Tags: java, arrays, list, spring-boot

I am trying to pass the List of String from one server to the another server in spring boot.
How i can get that list at the another server?

The code i have tried-

```
public void addNewMostPopular(List<String> totalList){  
    try {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = getHttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                BASE_URL + "addMostPopular/"+new ArrayList<>(totalList), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,TrendingCategoryDTO.class);
    }
```

and at server side i tried to get like-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addMostPopular/[{totalList}]", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addMostPopularProduct( @PathVariable List<String> totalList) {}
```

Comment: you should pass the list in body of request

Comment: Have you heard about post requests? You should use that for your problem, and it will be passed as the body of the request, in the payload of the request

Comment: For post requests, it is recommended to use request body

Comment: @RamanMishra can you please provide me some code example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past long object in the url is a bad praxis, thats because spring url interpreter has a maximun lenght, so if you pass more than 2048 or 4096 char in some cases your request will return Response 400 bad request and won't execute anycode on your spring server.

After this aclaration, is there any option to pass a list? Yes, of course! But we need use `@RequestBody`like this:

```
@PostMapping("/addMostPopular")
public void addMostPopularProduct(@RequestBody List<String> totalList) {
    // Your function
}
```

Now we need to add to our other server the List we want to pass to this request in the body of the request.

Comment: This answer to the question how pass data in a post request, not "How i can pass a list<String> to the server with URL"

Answer (score 0):

If you like to pass a List of values in the url one possibility is to pass them as url parameters.

You have to create a link similar to the followings:

```
http://youserver/youraction?param=first&param=second&param=third
```

or

```
http://youserver/youraction?param=first,second,third
```

Your controller in spring must be something like

```
@Controller 
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/youraction")
    public String yourAction(@RequestParam("param") List<String> params) {
       // Here params is tre list with the values first, second, third
    }
}
```

This action is able to handle both kind of requests that I wrote before.

Comment: but i need to pass the List values Using restTemplate

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass infomation between servers.
The simple way is to initiate an http request, based on your request method get or post put the parameters to the appropriate location : reuqest header or request body. You can do like @Davide Lorenzo MARINO.
Or use a message queue, like ActiveMq.
In the case of the same registry center, you can also use @feign to resolve it.